# Add or Remove Individual Cells in Confluence

Tags: confluence

I have a table in Confluence where certain cells have been deleted.

[image: Confluence table]

I can't find any way to add individual cells to complete the table, or to remove individual cells to cause the rest to shift "back into place".

I can add/remove an entire row/column, but there's nothing for individual cells. Is there a way to do this on a cell-by-cell basis?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that removing a cell is not a normal feature but an anomaly in the editor. The only option would be indeed to delete the entire column with missing cells.

Answer (score -1):

stand in the last column -> insert column after -> ctrl+z